# Juila: copy (pasteable and "human-readable") value to clipboard

Tags: julia

I have a large Julia structure that I would like to copy to the clipboard.

Using clipboard(string(x)) seems to put a "non-pasteable" (as in, giving syntax error) variant on my clipboard.

JLD etc. creates a binary file which isn't what I'm after.

How can I copy the *value* itself, in a way that is modifiable and pasteable into the Julia REPL later?

Example of non-pasteable: `clipboard(π)` (made with `clipboard(\pi)`).

Comment: Can you show your `x` that is problematic? In simple cases (e.g. arrays, tuples, structs) the process you describe works as you say you want. You even can simply write `clipboard(x)` without calling `string` on `x`.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński: it's a complicated structure (several megabytes). I can't really show it. Should `clipboard(x)` work for "everything", then, is that what you're saying?

Comment: It should work for most types, unless they have special treatment by `print` method. Typically if you do `print(x)` then what is printed can be copy-pasted to recreate the object. There are two buts: 1) e.g. `Float64` of course will be not represented exactly due to rounding; 2) some types cannot be copy-pasted like this, e.g. if you write `pi` then what is printed is `π = 3.1415926535897...` and it cannot be copy-pasted. The reason is that `pi` has `Irrational` type which is special. Another example is `big(10)` which will be printed as `10` and when-copy pasted will be converted to `Int`.

Comment: Interesting. Are there any "workarounds" for this that you would know of (feel free to post it/them as an answer)? For example, I wouldn't mind if clipboard(\pi) resulted in 3.1415926535897 on my clipboard so that I could paste it back without getting the error `syntax: "..." expression outside call`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in your question - an ideal way would be to serialize and deserialize an object, but unfortunately this approach will not work as e.g. on Windows clipboard will not accept NUL character.

There is no simple and 100% correct way to paste any object to a clipboard and reconstruct it later I know.
However, in most cases simply writing `clipboard(x)` when `x` is your object should work.
Then if you paste it in REPL and evaluate all should work, e.g.:

```
julia> x = Dict(:a=>1, "a"=>2, nothing=>[1,2,3, (1,2,3)])
Dict{Any,Any} with 3 entries:
  :a      => 1
  nothing => Any[1, 2, 3, (1, 2, 3)]
  "a"     => 2

julia> clipboard(x)
```

and now paste it in REPL to get:

```
julia> Dict{Any,Any}(Pair{Any,Any}(:a, 1),Pair{Any,Any}(nothing, Any[1, 2, 3, (1, 2, 3)]),Pair{Any,Any}("a", 2))
Dict{Any,Any} with 3 entries:
  :a      => 1
  nothing => Any[1, 2, 3, (1, 2, 3)]
  "a"     => 2

julia> Dict{Any,Any}(Pair{Any,Any}(:a, 1),Pair{Any,Any}(nothing, Any[1, 2, 3, (1, 2, 3)]),Pair{Any,Any}("a", 2)) == x
true
```

I use a pretty complex object on purpose.

The only limitation of this approach is that not objects are properly represented when printed (this is what `clipboard` does by default).

For example `BigInt(10)` is printed as `10` or `pi` is printed as `π = 3.1415926535897...`.

The consequence is the following:

```
julia> print(Any[BigInt(10), pi])
Any[10, π = 3.1415926535897...]
```

And we loose information that `10` was `BigInt` (it would be parsed as `Int`) and `pi` part will not parse.

A work-around is to override `show` methods for those offending types (although it is type piracy so be careful to limit the use of this approach). For instance:

```
julia> Base.show(io::IO, x::Irrational{sym}) where {sym} = print(io, "$sym")
WARNING: Method definition show(IO, Base.Irrational{sym}) in module Base at irrationals.jl:12 overwritten in module Main at REPL[31]:1.

julia> Base.show(io::IO, x::BigInt) = print(io, string("BigInt(",string(x),")"))
WARNING: Method definition show(IO, Base.GMP.BigInt) in module GMP at gmp.jl:569 overwritten in module Main at REPL[32]:1.

julia> print(Any[BigInt(10), pi])
Any[BigInt(10), π]
```

And now you can use `clipboard` again:

```
julia> x = Any[BigInt(10), π]
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 BigInt(10)
          π

julia> clipboard(x)
```

and if you paste clipboard to your REPL you get:

```
julia> Any[BigInt(10), π]
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 BigInt(10)
          π

julia> Any[BigInt(10), π] == x
true
```

Unfortunately you would have to do this for every offending type, which sometimes can be complex. For instance if you use sparse arrays their `print` method shows:

```
julia> print(sparse([1,2,3]))
  [1]  =  1
  [2]  =  2
  [3]  =  3
```

which would have to be completely rewritten and substituted by some constructor of sparse array, which is complex. You will get similar problems with e.g. malformed strings which do not print nicely by default.

Comment: I see. It is sad that this doesn't work. For pi for example, why could the unicode character for pi simply not get used in the clipboard? One would get the best of all worlds.